# Printing from SSRS Report Viewer without using ActiveX

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I've got a requirement where I need to use an SSRS Report Viewer, and we want to provide the users the ability to print the results.  Now normally that is accomplished via the in-built printing functionality of the Print Viewer, but that requires an Active X component.  We have no control over our consumer's environment and would like to eliminate this need for an Active X component.

I can't seem to find any resources on how to subvert the Active X aspect of printing.  Is there anyone out there who knows what I need to do in order to provide print functionality to the end users without downloading the component?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is anyway to override the behavior of the ReportViewer control in such a way as to allow for this.

Instead of using the ReportViewer control, you could render the report as a PDF and transmit the PDF back to the client browser.  Then, it could render using the Acrobat Reader plug-in.

Comment: It naturally has an "export to PDF" button, but we were hoping to let the end users print directly like the Active X lets them.

Comment: @JustLoren - I understand, but I guess my point was that if you render the PDF on the server and send the PDF back in the response, many browsers will display the PDF directly in the browser.  This may provide a smoother flow than making the user export the PDF and open it in a separate Adobe Reader instance.  Other than that, I don't think you can do what you want.